# address of a const object interpreted as low level const

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

In C++ Primer (5th edition) I found an example which doesn't make much sense to me:

```
const int i = /*some integer literal*/;

auto e = &i;
```

For me `&i` represents the address of `const int i` - so the address itself is not a (low/high level) const and `e` should be interpreted as `int *`.

But this book interprets `e` as  **const int*** stating the reason **(& of a const object is low-level const)** - Can someone please clarify what's wrong with my understanding.

Comment: `const int*` means the integer is const (which is correct). `int* const` means the pointer is const (which is not true as you say). So I think you are just misinterpreting what `const int*` means.

Comment: `e` is not const. You can modify it. To const qualify it the type would need to be `int * const`

Comment: Everything is clear here: `const int*` is a non-const pointer to const integer, `int* const` is a const pointer to non-const integer, `const int* const` is a const pointer to const integer

Comment: @john yeah, it was a typo - fixed :)

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Since `i` is a `const` object, the pointer to it should be a `const int*` to prevent modification - is it the reason that `e` is **adjusted** to `const int *`?

Comment: @john Since i is a const object, the pointer to it should be a const int* to prevent modification - is it the reason that e is adjusted to const int *?

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus Yes that's right. If `e` was `int*` then you could use `e` to modify `i`, which is not allowed since `i` is const.

Answer (score 0):

You assign an address to e using `auto` therefore e is a pointer.
The const applies to int, e points to a const int but e isn't a const pointer.
e would be a top level const if e was a const pointer which it is not, e is a non const pointer (ie you can assign other addresses to e) which points to a const int.
Therefore e is a low level const

```
int i = /*some integer literal*/;

const auto e = &i;
```

Now `e` is a const pointer to a non const int. Since the object itself `e` is const, this is a top level const

Answer (score 0):

From the book C++ Primer 5th Edition:

> ..., a pointer is an object that can point to a different object. As a
> result, we can talk independently about whether a pointer is const and
> whether the objects to which it can point are const. We use the term
> top-level const to indicate that the pointer itself is a const. When a
> pointer can point to a const object, we refer to that const as a
> low-level const.
>
> More generally, top-level const indicates that an object itself is
> const. Top-level const can appear in any object type, i.e., one of the
> built-in arithmetic types, a class type, or a pointer type. Low-level
> const appears in the base type of compound types such as pointers or
> references. Note that pointer types, unlike most other types, can have
> both top-level and low-level const independently:

```
int i = 0;
int *const p1 = &i; // we can't change the value of p1; const is top-level
const int ci = 42; // we cannot change ci; const is top-level
const int *p2 = &ci; // we can change p2; const is low-level
const int *const p3 = p2; // right-most const is top-level, left-most is not
const int &r = ci; // const in reference types is always low-level
```

Hope it helps for better understating.